# django special character handling

Tags: python, django, encoding

I'm trying to understand how to deal correctly with special characters in Django / Python.
I have added to my views.py and models.py the following encoding string:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But when the following cmd is called with a purchase order name set to "TestÄÜÖ" it crashes:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'The purchase order "%s" has been successfully added to project "%s".' % (purchase_order, project.name))
```

The error thrown is the following:

```
File "..accounting/views.py", line 1100, in post_logic
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'The purchase order "%s" has been successfully added to project "%s".' % (purchase_order, project.name))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The PurchaseOrder model looks like this.

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    """
    purchase order assigned to a project
    """

    number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default="")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.name, self.number)
```

The problem does not occur if I add `u` in front of the message string:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, u'The purchase order "%s" has been successfully added to project "%s".' % (purchase_order, project.name))
```

But the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#general-string-handling) say that in Django 1.5 (I'm using 1.5) a normal string should be a unicode string and there is no need for the `u` .

So I do not want to add to all my add_message calls an `u`, if the docs say it is not needed.
Anybody can shed some light on this encoding topic?

Comment: Try it with `purchase_order.encode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `from __future__ import unicode_literals` that would make strings in Python2 act like Python3 unicode strings.